# find the 5 largest (by number of lines) files at git repository

Tags: linux, git, zsh

**My aim:**
I want to start working on a new OpenSource project.
project by link: https://github.com/dry-python/returns/tree/master/returns
First, I need to understand what files I have to work with?

**Task:**
The task is to sort the files by the number of lines of code, find the 5 files with the most lines.
What command in the console can I use for this?

**What I have already done:**

1. Uploaded the repository files to my local machine into a directory called "returns-master"
2. Run the command:

```
ls / returns-master | wc -l | sort -n | head -n 5
```

In response, I get an error:

```
ls: returns-master: No such file or directory
17
```

Comment: This probably won't involve git, as long as the code has already been checked out. This seems more suited for https://superuser.com/

Comment: @Vladimir: Do you only care about files in a particular checked out commit or are you interested in the entire project history?

Comment: @SimonFromme, I'm only interested in the files of the checked out commit. Not about history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the git repo first. Then find the desired files on the disk:

```
find /path/to/your/copy/of/repo -type f | xargs wc -l | sort -gr | head -n6 | tail -n +2 | perl -lane 'print $F[-1]'
```

Here, `find` passes the list of files in the checked out git repo to `xargs`, which feeds them to `wc -l`, which counts the lines.
`sort -gr` : Sort in reverse by the first column (number of lines).
`head -n6 | tail -n +2` : Grab the top 6 entries returned by `wc`, which includes the first one with the `total`, which we remove using `tail`.
 `perl -lane 'print $F[-1]'` : Print the last column delimited by whitespace ( the file names).

Answer (score 0):

You need a shell that supports the `**` glob. I think `zsh` does by default, and in `bash` you need `shopt -s globstar`. You can try `sort` instead of `gsort`, too.

```
wc -l **/*(.)| gsort -n
```

You can add  `| gtail -n 6` to get only the top five.

To get only `.zsh` files:

```
wc -l **/*.zsh | gsort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git ls-files | xargs wc -l | sort -gr | head -n20
```

https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git+ls-files+%7C+xargs+wc+-l+%7C+sort+-gr+%7C+head+-n20